# How come my javascript doesn't work when I put my HTML in an "include"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, css, django

```
{% include "abc.html" %}
```

In Django, I put my html in this.

Now, my javascript won't work.

```
$(function(){
   alert('hi');
   $(".div_inside_abc").css("background","#000");

});
```

I even tried putting this javascript inside abc.html (at the top). It still won't work.

When I do:

```
$(".div_inside_abc").each(function(e){
    document.write($(this).attr("data-rel"));
});
```

I get this:

```
{{p.grid_image_ur l}}{{p.grid_image_ur l}}{{p.grid_image_ur l}}{{p.grid_image_ur l}}{{p.grid_image_ur l}}{{p.grid_image_ur l}}
```

That's not normal! It's as if Django's template is not rendering when I "include" something.

Comment: Is jQuery being referenced properly?

Comment: And do you have an element with the class `div_inside_abc`?

Comment: You should post the generated HTML.  That will greatly help both you and us to see the issue.

Comment: And you should be using Firefox/Firebug to chase down in-browser JS problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put JavaScript code inside HTML it won't execute (or be valid HTML). You have to wrap it in a *SCRIPT* tag if you're going to do it that way (which I don't advise) or as a DOM1 attribute.

If you want jQuery to run this function on load I'd suggest doing this in an externally referenced JavaScript file that's loaded after jQuery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('hi');
    $(".div_inside_abc").css("background","#000");
});
```

Or adding it inline as,

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('hi');
        $(".div_inside_abc").css("background","#000");
});
</script>
```

after the jQuery include.

If you want this to be evaluated arbitrarily I'd suggest invoking the function directly this way (if you need the scope)

```
(function(){
    alert('hi');
    $(".div_inside_abc").css("background","#000");

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

In abc.html change {{p.grid_image_ur l}} to {{ p.grid_image_url }}. May not be it, but is a good start. The page must be throwing an error that for some reason you can't see.